# How is fishing in the European Union structured?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, fishing

As an island in the Atlantic the UK has the right to fish large swathes of ocean off its coast: a 200 nautical mile exclusive economic zone (EEZ).

I think this is how it works inside the EU: the UK relinquishes the right to the EEZ. Up to 12 nautical miles offshore is exclusive to UK boats and the rest is shared via a system of quotas with the other EU member states.

How are quotas shared among member states - does everyone get an equal catch quota?

And why is this resource shared in this way? The coal fields in Germany and the oil in the North Sea are not shared in this way. So why are the fish in the UK EEZ?

Comment: Steel and coal were among the first to be covered by the predecessors of the EU ...

Comment: Were the raw materials/resources shared, or was the infrastructure to process coal and steel shared?

Comment: It was a question of sharing *market access*, so that previously national companies were no longer national companies but European ones acting in a supranational market. Instead of a German of French steel industry, there was an European steel industry with facilities in different countries. Read about the [ECSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Coal_and_Steel_Community). The infrastructure still belonged to capitalists and shareholders.

Comment: Thank you. So I think my question still stands. Why is the fishing resource itself shared, unlike, for example, coal?

Comment: The EU rules allow tradespeople or bankers to work in any state of the Union. Why make an exception for fishermen?

Comment: Shouldn't those distances be nautical miles, rather than miles?

Comment: @origimbo, such details don't affect the core of the question. If a country is in the EU, should *any* EU citizen be allowed to fish their seas or just the locals? How does fishery differ from bidding on public works, or selling insurance? Does the nature of fisheries make them special?

Comment: What do you actually want to know? Have you perused the relevant Wikipedia articles? It seems to me that you are asking several rather broad and somewhat biased questions with some unstated agenda in the back of your mind…

Comment: I think it's important to clarify that the EEZ is technically still international territory. This is distinct from sovereign territory (e.g. land, or ocean within the 12-mile limit). While international treaties give certain states preferential access to resources within the EEZ, the status of EEZ territory (and thus the resources therein) are categorically different from the status of on-land or within-territorial-waters territories (and resources).

Comment: @o.m. The UK has a “sovereign right” (the United Nations terminology) to exclusively exploit the EEZ undersea, seabed and subsoil. EU fishermen should (and do) hold the right to work anywhere in the EU. And this could be permitted while maintaining the EEZ. But the EU demands forfeiture. Hence my question.

Comment: @Ben Continuing to use words like “relinquish”, “give up”, “demands” and “forfeiture” after you have received numerous explanations make it hard to believe you're genuinely seeking understanding. The EEZ is being fully “maintained”, EU states haven't given up their claims with respects to outsiders, they have agreed to manage it together.

Answer (score 12):

It's only part of the story but it's easy to find a justification for a Common Fisheries Policy: Fish moves around and depletion of the resource impacts everybody. So much so that there are in fact other international organisations dealing with this issue to which the EU defers in part when setting its “total allowable catch”. Beyond that, the story is somewhat similar to the Common Agricultural Policy: It was there from the start (and as such a “take it or leave it” proposition for subsequent would-be members) and is sustained by powerful constituencies.

Besides, it's not just the “fish of the UK EEZ” that is being shared and the UK hasn't “relinquished” anything. The regulation and resources are *pooled*, which is not quite the same. The sector-by-sector zero-sum view of EU policies that is so common in the UK is short-sighted but in this case the UK might be a net beneficiary: UK quotas are the second largest in the EU and their overall share of the total allowable catch is larger than what is being caught in the UK EEZ. As always with trade, what's really at stake are competing local interests (big boats vs. large boats, specific fisheries, supermarkets, consumers…) and long-term sustainability rather than the interests of the country as a whole.

Comment: Numerous examples of actions of neighbouring states impacting others eg. CO2 emissions “move” globally - yet EU oil/coal fields are not “pooled resources.” Instead, multilateral agreements ensure fair resource management to avoid too much harm to one another. As to “relinquish”: the definition is “to voluntarily give up claim to.” That is precisely what the UK (and other members) sign up to when they become (or continue to be) members. They relinquish the claim for the duration of their membership to their 200nm EEZ. An island in the Atlantic, I would expect UK quota to be relatively large.

Comment: @Ben That's why the EU adopted *several* package of measures regarding CO2 emissions. Meanwhile, coal just doesn't move, that's a simple fact. None of this changes anything to the clear justification for fisheries management. It would still be completely valid if the EU had never taken any measures regarding coal, CO2 or any other sector. At this point it sounds to me as if you're grasping at straws and becoming argumentative, which is why I asked what you *really* wanted to know.

Comment: I “really” want to know the answer to the question in the... question. The subtext is all my lived experiences. There’s always a subtext. On CO2 the resources have not been pooled or shared. The CO2 emissions measures are an example of managing harm to neighbours _without_ sharing the resource itself. For fish, the UK could have instead signed up to a multilateral framework of catch quotas to avoid overfishing impacting neighbouring stocks. But this is not how fishing is designed in the EU: the resource itself is shared (as I understand it). Hence my question.

Comment: ...and if I challenge your answer it is not because I am being argumentative. It is because doing so helps me strengthen my understanding.

Comment: @Ben You asked at least two or three very broad questions, I gave you the answer to the main one and you just won't accept it, which leads me to believe you're interested in something else. As I already wrote, the comparison with other sectors is neither here nor there to understand how fishing in the EU is structured or why resources are pooled but as a matter of *fact*, for CO2, the resources *are* pooled. That's *exactly* what an emission trading scheme is.

Comment: And what differences do you make between the CFP and a “multilateral framework of catch quotas”? In the CFP, the resource are pooled and then distributed between the member states according to some agreed rules. In this case, the UK and a few other countries like the Netherlands and Denmark actually get more than it provides overall, much to the chagrin of French and Spanish fishermen and therefore gains some share of fishing in other countries EEZ. It hasn't “given up“ or “relinquished” anything as fishing is not a free-for-all and certainly not open to those outside the framework.

Comment: This feels like a heated discussion and I don’t know why. I am simply exploring your answer. CO2 isn’t a resource (for the most part: fizzy drinks, some industrial applications). CO2 in this context is the harmful externality. Coal or oil is the resource. And these are not shared or pooled.

Comment: Re my “multilateral framework of catch quotas”. The key point was that pooling of the resource is not a prerequisite for managing harm to neighbours. So my question still stands: why is the resource pooled? There may be a very good reason: I just want to know what it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89324/discussion-between-relaxed-and-ben).

Comment: "UK hasn't “relinquished” anything" well they have - they've relinquished the EEZ being their EEZ, in exchange for being part of the EU (and the fishing pool, although the reason for the relinquishment was joining the EU/EEC ).